# Fast Python min-cut library with BSD license

Tags: python, graph, cython, mathematical-optimization, max-flow

Is there a fast cython/python library for doing maximum flow / minimum cut computations (preferably with Boykov-Kolmogorov) that has a BSD license?

A light-weight C library would also be useful.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4008997/5085211

Comment: Did you find a `C` implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58815407/5085211) which also includes a simple benchmark, SciPy -- which is licensed under BSD-3 -- includes an implementation as of 1.4.0 as `scipy.sparse.csgraph.maximum_flow`.

Answer (score 2):

There is [Graph-Tool](http://projects.skewed.de/graph-tool/) which is GPL licensed or [Python-Graph](http://code.google.com/p/python-graph/) which is MIT licensed, depending on what you can live with.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you have any experience with Python-Graph wrt speed?

Comment: I can't comment on the speed of Python-Graph, but I do find Graph-Tool to be fast enough for me.  If you have speed issues with Python-Graph you can always look at compilers like Psyco or PyPy to execute the code faster.

Answer (score 1):

How about [NetworkX](http://networkx.lanl.gov/)? Check out their [flow-related algorithms](http://networkx.lanl.gov/reference/algorithms.flow.html).

The license is BSD

Comment: Thanks. NetworkX is pure Python though, and therefore painfully slow.

Comment: @AndreasMueller You can run it through Psyco then to see if it's any faster.

Comment: @ChristianWitts: is Psyco still alive?

Comment: @larsmans It's been declared discontinued since March 2012, so it's only freshly dead. PyPy would probably be the best current choice, but it doesn't support everything yet.

Comment: @ChristianWitts: OTOH, if NetworkX is indeed pure Python, there's little reason why it shouldn't run on PyPy, and since its data is relatively regular, I would expect nice speedups

Comment: Eli I also thought about that but I want to use it in combination with code that uses Numpy.... could try but might be non-trivial