Select Unique Pairs from Pyspark Dataframe
Let's assume, I have a PySpark data frame:
X Y
1 a
1 b
1 c
2 b
2 a
2 c
3 a
3 c
3 b
4 p

I have to select any possible pair, of X and Y, but same X and Y should not be repeated in result.
Possible output 1
X Y
1 b
2 c
3 a
4 p

Possible output 2
X Y
2 a
1 b
3 c
4 p

How to achieve this efficiently? The given data frame, can be very large.

Seems like a graph problem, is there a limit on the values of X or Y for (example Y is letters between 'a' and 'z' so at maximum 26 values)

Check below code.
You have to collect column Y values using collect_list function then use array_distinct to eliminate duplicates and then use filter to match values of X and Y
WITH output AS (
    SELECT
    X,
    Y,    
    FILTER(
        ARRAY_DISTINCT(
            COLLECT_LIST(Y) OVER(ORDER BY 1)
        ),
        (ELEM, INDEX) -> ELEM == Y AND INDEX + 1 == X
    )[0] AS f
    FROM VALUES 
        (1, "a"), 
        (1, "b"), 
        (1, "c"), 
        (2, "b"), 
        (2, "a"), 
        (2, "c"), 
        (3, "a"), 
        (3, "c"), 
        (3, "b"), 
        (4, "p"),
        (5, "e"),
        (5, "f"),
        (6, "a"),
        (6, "b") AS (X, Y)
) 
SELECT X, Y FROM output 
WHERE f IS NOT NULL


+---+---+
|X  |Y  |
+---+---+
|1  |a  |
|2  |b  |
|3  |c  |
|4  |p  |
|5  |e  |
+---+---+

OR Check below without collect_list.
WITH input AS (
    SELECT        
       X,
       Y    
   FROM VALUES 
        (1, "a"), 
        (1, "b"), 
        (1, "c"), 
        (2, "b"), 
        (2, "a"), 
        (2, "c"), 
        (3, "a"), 
        (3, "c"), 
        (3, "b"), 
        (4, "p"),
        (5, "e"),
        (5, "f"),
        (6, "a"),
        (6, "b") AS (X, Y)
),
INPUT_Y (  
  SELECT     
    monotonically_increasing_id() + 1 as id,
    Y 
  FROM (
    SELECT DISTINCT Y FROM INPUT
  )   
)
SELECT 
   /*+ BROADCAST(R) */
   L.X, 
   L.Y 
FROM INPUT L 
INNER JOIN INPUT_Y R
ON L.X = R.ID AND L.Y = R.Y

+---+---+
|X  |Y  |
+---+---+
|1  |a  |
|2  |c  |
|3  |b  |
|4  |p  |
|5  |f  |
+---+---+


This will actually move all data into a single partition, which is not good for performance.

Ok, done added other solution without collect_list.

More likely this solution won't be maximal. In that sense if I select [(1,a), (1,b)] and then there is (5,a) if (1,a) gets selected then (5,a) has no chance. but there exists [(5,a),(1,b)]  solution.

Good, Point.. let me check. Thanks

As @ Abdennacer Lachiheb  mentioned in the comment, this is indeed a bipartite matching problem. Unlikely to get solved correctly in pyspark or using graphframes. The best would to solve it using a graph algorithm library's hopcroft_karp_matching like NetworkX. Or use scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment
hopcroft_karp_matching : pure python code, runs in O(E√V) time, where E is the number of edges and V is the number of vertices in the graph.
scipy.optimize.linear_sum_assignment : O(n^3) complexity but written in c++.
So only practical testing on the data can determine which works better on your data sizes.
Read more for discussion here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/49552057/3238085
https://stackoverflow.com/a/4436206/3238085
NetworkX solve this bipartite maximal matching problem using Hopcroft-Karp algorithm.
Here's are two such solutions :
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms import bipartite


def first_method():
    data = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'c'),
            (3, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'p')]

    B = nx.Graph()

    B.add_nodes_from(set(x for x, y in data), bipartite=0)  # Set X
    B.add_nodes_from(set(y for x, y in data), bipartite=1)  # Set Y

    B.add_edges_from(data)

    top_nodes = set(x for x, y in data)

    matching = nx.algorithms.bipartite.matching.hopcroft_karp_matching(B, top_nodes=top_nodes)

    filtered_matching = {x: y for x, y in matching.items() if x in top_nodes}

    print("Matching pairs:")
    for x, y in filtered_matching.items():
        print(f"{x} - {y}")


def second_method():
    import numpy as np
    from scipy.optimize import linear_sum_assignment


    data = [(1, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (1, 'c'), (2, 'b'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'c'),
            (3, 'a'), (3, 'c'), (3, 'b'), (4, 'p')]

    X, Y = zip(*data)
    X_unique = sorted(set(X))
    Y_unique = sorted(set(Y))

    cost_matrix = np.full((len(X_unique), len(Y_unique)), fill_value=np.inf)

    for x, y in data:
        i = X_unique.index(x)  # Row index
        j = Y_unique.index(y)  # Column index
        cost_matrix[i, j] = 1  # Set cost to 1 for existing connections

    row_ind, col_ind = linear_sum_assignment(cost_matrix)

    print("Matching pairs:")
    for i, j in zip(row_ind, col_ind):
        print(f"{X_unique[i]} - {Y_unique[j]}")


first_method()
second_method()

Output :
Matching pairs:
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
4 - p

Matching pairs:
1 - a
2 - b
3 - c
4 - p


It's the correct solution, but networkx doesn't work with the dataframe api, so the OP will not be able to run this with a spark dataframe
